# Using Kudu with multi-instance app service in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu, azure-app-service-plans, azure-web-app-for-containers

In Azure I have a Linux Web App (for containers) running under an app service plan of 2 instances (set under the "Scale out" menu item). If I understood correctly, this corresponds to my application being hosted on two separate VM instances in Azure.

If I then use the debug console in the Kudu interface (Developement Tools-> Advanced Tools) what am I actually logging on to ? Is it one of the VMs which hosts my Docker container ? If so why am I not prompted to choose the VM (seeing as I configured 2 in the plan) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters let me clarify something: Azure Web App != Azure Virtual Machine.

Moving on Hosting plans are logical containers for web apps and each web app will have its own kudo with a different url usually by adding scm  to the URL for example :

http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/ = WebApp URL

https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/ = KUDU URL

Kudu will give you the ability to access the WebApp root where your website + some additional configuration files and folders exist.

you don't get to choose because kudu gives you an access to the WebApp, not the Hosting plan and as such go to your second web and you should see a different kudu.

would you please clarify some stuff so you can get a better help.

> In Azure I have a Linux Web App (for containers) running under an app service plan of 2 instances. If I understood correctly, this corresponds to my application being hosted on two separate VM instances in Azure.

Are you using containers as a deployment method ? to deploy to a web app? that exists in a hosting plan ? that contain another two instances?

is this assumption correct?

Comment: In response to your questions, I prefer to use the Azure nomenclature to avoid confusion. I created an app service plan for linux where I selected to have 2 instances (I assumed this related to VMs, but perhaps I am mistaken). I then deployed a single web app (packaged as a container, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/) into the aforementioned app service plan. I hope that answers your questions.

Comment: Part1: so basically you have an app service plan with 2 ap services running inside. I apologize I did some research and I must admit I am more accustomed to another naming which would be hosting plans for app service plan and web apps for app service.

Comment: There is only one app service. I edited the original post to make this clearer and also what I mean when I talk of "2 instances".

Comment: Ahhh I see, 2 instances mean that you have scaled out "scaling horizontally" look here 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/scaling-up-and-scaling-out-in-windows-azure-web-sites/
now when you scale out you don't get another app service what you really get is another App Pool or its equivalents in your chosen server software. so, in short, it's not another app service that you need to maintain.
so when you log into Kudo you are simply accessing your code files and binaries alongside a PowerShell/CMD/Bash Window to perform some light tasks.

Comment: just putting out my thoughts : the whole point of App services/ Web apps is that you don't have to maintain a VM meaning MS will maintain the environment for you while you only care about your development, if you are looking into having to deployment destinations i'd suggest 
1 - utilize app service deployment slots.
2 - Scale down and create another app service "not app service plan".

Comment: Thanks for this, I was confused by the word "instances" when scaling horizontally as I immediately assumed this would relate to an additional VM behind the scenes, but I imagine the actual infrastructure is more subtle and as you say, the idea is that one should not worry about the environment as it is taken care of my MS.